# Пауза входе выполнения кода

Tags: python, таймер

Друзья, помогите грамотно осуществить паузу в процессе выполнения кода python по определенной клавише, допустим это будет клавиша "P" И по этой самой клавише нужно возобновить выполнение кода. (Если это вообще возможно) Заранее спасибо. Код:

```
`import keyboard
    import pyautogui
    import time
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        keyboard.press("1")
        sleep(1)
        keyboard.press("t")
        sleep(1)
        print(Fore.RED + 'Запуск..')
        keyboard.release("t")
        keyboard.write("Привет всем!")
        sleep(5)
        keyboard.press("ENTER")
        print(Fore.GREEN + 'Стоп!')
        sleep(2)
        pyautogui.click(button='right')
        pyautogui.moveTo(816, 528, 0.5)
        pyautogui.click(button='left')
        pyautogui.moveTo(851, 401, 0.5)
        pyautogui.click(button='left')
        sleep(5)`
```

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep(5)`

Если я все правильно понял

Comment: А если я в рандомное время хочу остановить и аналогично запустить код?

Comment: то в цикле ожидаешь действия которое остановит паузу. Тут уже были подобные вопросы. Потом можешь через второй поток останавливать первый по нажатиям.